# Regular expression match file version pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am new to Regex .I want to match pattern of my file ..
like 1.2.2. same as 1.2.3.

because sometime there is bug like 1.2.4.3. so I want to ignore that one.

Is this possible with regex only get file having pattern = 1.2.2. means x.y.z.

please suggest some good example or ans if possible ..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if a string is of the `1.2.3` format by using a regex like this:

```
^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$
```

`1.2.3.4` would not match.

Comment: @Satyam, you need to be more specific than that. Also note that you need to quote regex properly in Java, like `"^\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+$"`.

Comment: Thanks Qtax..I just forgot to do so..but its run..tx

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
.+?=([0-9]+\.){2}[0-9]+[^\.]+
```

It recognizes pattern like this:

Mylib=0.0.1(+whatever that is not a dot)

Edited due to the note

Comment: No, it doesn't, as `\w` doesn't include `-`. And it would require a dot after the last digit.

Comment: Maybe your regex engine does'nt recognizes Lazy quantifier (+?), or require start & end line ('^' at the beginning and '$' at the end)

Comment: additionnaly, in Java you must double slashes ('\\' instead of '\')